# CSS transition on png sequence using steps

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I'm trying to make an animation using a PNG sequence, which has a transition on hover, and animates back when the hover state ends.

For this I'm using a css transition with a "steps" timing function, like so:

```
transition:background .5s steps(9, end);
```

See the fiddle for a live example (I've used a random PNG sprite that I Googled, it's not the one I'm actually using)

http://jsfiddle.net/MLWL5/

Basically this is working fine, when you hover over the element slowly. When you quickly hover on and off the element, the transition seems to trigger when the background image if halfway through the previous transition, and then the number of steps don't match which will get an undesired effect.

I could use javascript to trigger the transition, but does anyone know if there's a CSS only solution for this?

Comment: If you look at the image, I think you'll find that it's not one long strip (http://www.photoshopgurus.com/forum/attachments/photoshop-newbies/1638d1292612974t-png-sequence-cinema-4d-rosu_1filmstrip.png)

Comment: Yes I know, I'm only using the top row. I could crop out the rest of the image but it would give the same effect.

Comment: To avoid any confusion, I edited the fiddle, now using an image which is only one horizontal row.

Comment: It works ok if you don't set the transition on the un-hover http://jsfiddle.net/MLWL5/1/

Comment: That's true, but I want the particular animation that I'm working with to animate backwards when you un-hover.

Comment: I believe this plugin will help you: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a perfect solution, but you can have it somehow working handling the hover change with an animation instead.

It will work ok if you un-hover after the animation has finished, but it won't animate at all if you un-hover quickly

CSS

```
div { width:50px; 
    height:72px;             background:url(http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/_images/duke_spritesheet.png) left top;
    transition:background 1.5s steps(9, end);
    background-position: 0px top; 
    -webkit-animation: none;
}

div:hover { 
    background-position:-450px top; 
    -webkit-animation: bkg 1.5s steps(9);
    transition: none;

} 

@-webkit-keyframes bkg {
    0% {background-position: 0px top;}
  100% {background-position: -450px top;}
}
```

### [CSS demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MLWL5/3/)

And, a solution using jQuery. This one rewinds the animation from the point where it was at the un-hover moment. It also recalculates the time, so that it doesn't slow down

jQuery

```
$( "div" ).hover(
    function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        var cur = parseInt(elem.css("background-position-x"));
        var steps = (450 + cur) / 50;
        var time = steps * 0.1;
        var trans = "background " + time + "s steps(" + steps + ", end)";
        elem.css("transition", trans);
        elem.css("background-position", "-450px 0px");
    }, 
    function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        var cur = parseInt(elem.css("background-position-x"));
        var steps = - cur / 50;
        var time = steps * 0.1;
        var trans = "background " + time + "s steps(" + steps + ", end)";
        elem.css("transition", trans);
        elem.css("background-position", "0px 0px");
  }
);
```

### [jQuery demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MLWL5/6/)

The jQuery code can be streamlined a little, using functions to avoid duplicate code, but I have set it to be as clear as posible

Comment: The jQuery solutions looks really nice. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone interested in a somewhat advanced version of vals' jQuery solution, check this one out: http://jsfiddle.net/GustvandeWal/MLWL5/138/. In this Fiddle, you are required to explicitly set the background-size, since the jQuery uses it in its calculations. Besides that, it's completely independent of the rest of the parameters.