# css transition steps fails when mouse leavs element to early

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a question about the CSS3 steps() function.

When you enter the element with your mouse, the transition starts.
When you're mouse leaves the element before the animation is ready, it returns to it's original state. But the steps() isn't working anymore. Is there a workaround for this?

My fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1t5u3r3L/)

My SCSS:

```
    * {
    background: #f00;
}

.block {
                width: 38px;
                height: 38px;
                background-image: url('http://s8.postimg.org/gr7lvdms5/sprite_test.png');
                transition: all 0.5s steps(15);
                background-position: 0 0;
                position: absolute;
                left: 100px;
                top: 100px;

                &:hover {
                    background-position: -570px 0;
                }
            }
```

Can somebody help me with this?

PS: I already found this: [CSS transition on png sequence using steps 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962329/css-transition-on-png-sequence-using-steps), but this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why doesn't solve your problem the answer that you link ?

Comment: It doesn't solve my answer because I want it to run always on mouse over, these thread starts running when the mouse leaves.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a workaround by using 3D transforms. From your code, I have added the `transform` to flip the arrow, and a `transition` for the `transform`:

```
transform: rotateX( 0deg );
transition:transform 0.5s;

&:hover {
        transform: rotateX( -180deg );
    }
```

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/1t5u3r3L/1/

Comment: Hi Alvaro, thanks for your answer! This indeed solves this problem. Next problem is, that there is also an situation that the square is filled completly white, so the arrows pulls the square to white. This is why I chose sprites.

Comment: I don't understand. Wouldn't that be a problem with your current picture too? The arrow would be white over a white background