# How to use the PNG sequence in a single file in HTML / Javascript?

Tags: html, animation, png, sequence, clip-path

I remarked the PNG sequence files are either multiple files or a single file which contains all sequences. I can't figure it out if the two types of sequences have different names (and if yes what are these names). Further I try to find out how to use the image sequence j a SINGLE FILE like this one here[image]

for HTML / javascript animations. I think I need a div which moves over the png file (clip path), but I can't find any example. Maybe you know some? Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't you rather make a gif from that image?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It might be, this is the actual question: what is the usage of such files which contain multpile sequences. Is there any usage directly in HTML (javascript, node, angular, css... )?

Comment: You mean: How to use eg. gifs in HTML? Normally: `<img src="someImage.gif">`. If you use it this way, it will be normally animated.

Comment: No, I meant, how to use directly the image sequence in frontend, not as GIF, but as .png file which contains multiple sequences. Is this anyway possible?

Comment: So didnt you want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962329/css-transition-on-png-sequence-using-steps ?

Comment: You are right, thank you! Would you write a short answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but I can animate horizontally (or vertically) only. If you stack your images side to side horizontally, it will be perfect.

```css
.animatedImage {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuEev.png);
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  
  animation: png-animation 1s steps(3) forwards; /* To change speed of animation, change firs number; To include more images, change number in steps() */
  animation-iteration-count:infinite; /* Make animation never ends */
}

@keyframes png-animation {

  to {
    background-position: -1500px 0px;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="animatedImage"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can animate in both directions too! There is a great article here (https://medium.com/jspoint/creating-css-animations-using-sprite-sheet-47e2b7a3793c), but I've edited the code for your example below.

```css
div#cat {
    height: 256px;
    width: 512px;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuEev.png"); /* width: 2048px; height: 512px; */
    animation: playX 0.5s steps(4) infinite, playY 1s steps(2) infinite; /* The seconds for playX should be the playY divided by the amount of rows */
}
@keyframes playX {
  from {background-position-x: 0px;}
  to {background-position-x: -2048px;}
}
@keyframes playY {
  from {background-position-y: 0px;}
  to {background-position-y: -512px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="cat"></div>
```